# Apple says The app references non-public selectors in my app. What does that mean?

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

I have just uploaded an app and Application Loader has given me this warning. I went on to see what does this mean and found that I am using some third party APIs due to which it might get rejected. Can I know due to which library or which code is it saying like this?

Also, is my app really gonna get rejected for sure? I don't wanna wait for 10-12 days and then know that my app got rejected. How do I confirm this thing that it won't or would get rejected  in a shorter time?? Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Apple know you are using private API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842357/how-does-apple-know-you-are-using-private-api)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay got the answer myself. The Flurry SDK which I was using was an older Version V2. When I updated to V3 and the problem is resolved. Anyways thanks. :)

p.s You can check if your Flurry is outdated by checking your header file. If it says, FlurryAPI.h it is V2 and if it says FlurryAnalytics its V3.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using some undocumented method in your app.