# How can I know if I'm using private frameworks? 

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

I am developing an app for the App Store. However it is in an early stage, and not ready to be submitted to iTunes Connect (Needs things like screenshots, app icons, support URL, etc.) Apparently listing the app on iTunes Connect is required to use Xcode's validate option. I am registered with the Apple Developer Program.

If you know another way to use Xcode's Validate without iTunes Connect, that would be awesome.

Is there a third party test suite, a list of public vs. private (allowed/not allowed) frameworks somewhere, or something else I can use to "validate" my app?

Here are a few examples that I've come across but am unsure of:

```
#import <sys/sysctl.h>
#import <mach/mach.h>
#import <mach/mach_host.h>
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <IOKit/IOKit.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/sockio.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use appscanner https://github.com/ChimpStudios/App-Scanner

From developer description

> App Scanner is a preflight submission check list for iOS developers. 
>   It searches code for private API usage.  It is not perfect.

Other ways are listed here [How does Apple know you are using private API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842357/how-does-apple-know-you-are-using-private-api)

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <IOKit/IOKit.h>
```

Will get rejection.
Check https://github.com/ChimpStudios/App-Scanner