# Does Apple allow the usage of sysctl.h within iOS applications?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, iphone-privateapi, sysctl

Does Apple allow the usage of sysctl.h within iOS applications?

PS: [App Scanner](https://github.com/AndrewSchenk/App-Scanner), a third party tool that checks code for possible private-API usage seems to think it's okay.

**Note:** 
There is one more question like this : [How can I know if I'm using private frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311003/how-can-i-know-if-im-using-private-frameworks)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 3):

With the usual disclaimer that nobody can tell you what a reviewer **will** do, I can say for sure that there are apps in the store that use `sysctl` functions.

(Minor point: Simply including a header isn't a problem since symbols there shouldn't be visible in your app unless they're used...it's the things you use that might get flagged rather than what's included.)