# Can i get iPhone purchase/first time use date

Tags: ios

My requirement is to fetch purchase date of iOS device. Can it is possible through code.

Comment: Answer - is not possible to detect. So stop fight with it.

Comment: No not possible. That info even if available on device would not be exposed by API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no. Best you can get is information on when the device was turned on

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

struct timeval boottime;

int mib[2] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_BOOTTIME};
size_t size = sizeof(boottime);
time_t now;
time_t uptime = -1;

(void)time(&now);

if (sysctl(mib, 2, &boottime, &size, NULL, 0) != -1 && boottime.tv_sec != 0) {
    uptime = now - boottime.tv_sec;
}

NSDate *bootDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:((NSTimeInterval)-uptime)]
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this heavily relies on private APIs, so Apple *will* reject your app from the App Store if you have this functionality in it.

Comment: [Not necessarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140756/does-apple-allow-the-usage-of-sysctl-h-within-ios-applications). Besides, if this api wasn't supposed to be used, it wouldn't be exposed.

Comment: Private APIs are private for a reason. If you use a private API and get caught, your app will get rejected, since it against AppStore's rules. There are quire a few private APIs that developers have found, but being able to use something is not the same as being allowed to use it...