# Would apple allow this this non-public method?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am using some non-public method to better control the slide effects of my application, for example:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerWithTransition:2];
```

After trying to upload my App with the Application Loader I got the message that I can not use such non-public methods. I found in stackoverflow a nice workaround here: [How does Apple know you are using private API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842357/how-does-apple-know-you-are-using-private-api)

So, I've adapted my code:

```
int tvalue = 2;
objc_msgSend(self, sel_getUid("dismissModalViewControllerWithTransition:"), tvalue);
```

After changing the code, the Application Loader did accept my binary. So here my question: can I get any problems when the App gets revised by apple?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the answer to the question you are referring to, the string "dismissModalViewControllerWithTransition:" could be detected. You would need to hide the string. Transform it in some way or even crypt it in the code and decrypt it on runtime :)

Comment: @Hermann Klecker-Do you know any thread here in stackoverflow explaining how to do this encryption/decryption? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have decided not to use the non-public methods. I have used instead some animations, as described in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412467/dismissmodalviewcontroller-with-transition-left-to-right/11413093#11413093.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Your app was not rejected because Apple could not track properly your code. Skip using non-public methods.