# supported way to get a reference to the webBrowserView inside a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Is there a supported way to do this?  Not NSStringFromClass.  An actual supported way to get that reference.

Comment: Well, `NSStringFromClass()` won't help you with this anyway, but why do you think it's "unsupported"?

Comment: It will help me if I go through the tree underneath my webView looking for one whose class is UIWebBrowserView.  But if Apple renames that class, this would break.  So it is "supported" in the sense that I am not using any private API.  But it is not supported in the sense that there is no guarantee it will continue to work in the future.

Comment: In this case, there cannot possibly exist a method with which you can make sure it works. If it's private, it's subject to change, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question: No, there is not a supported way to do this.

It may be there, but if it is not exposed through the [`UIWebView` interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (or related classes), it's internal/private, and not meant to be accessed in a supported way.

Keep in mind that you *could* access it to play around, but it's likely that if your app uses any [internal API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842357/how-does-apple-know-you-are-using-private-api) when trying to submit to the app store, it will likely be rejected.