# How to check if I used unsupport methods？

Tags: ios, methods

My app support iOS5+，but sometimes others add some method available in iOS6+ or iOS7+.
is there any fast way to tell me there exist unsupport methods in project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are checking whether your app **uses private frameworks**, you can try [AppScanner](https://github.com/ChimpStudios/App-Scanner).

From developer description

> App Scanner is a preflight submission check list for iOS developers.
>   It searches code for private API usage. It is not perfect.

Here are [some other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842357/how-does-apple-know-you-are-using-private-api) too.

If you are worried about iOS 5 support, why not to run your app on iOS5-simulator or device?